# How to merge specific column from another dataframe in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe df1 and df2, in df1 I have 'id', 'name', 'rol' and in df2 I have 'id', 'sal', 'add', 'deg'.

I have to merge only `'sal'` and `'deg'` column from df2 to df1.

I have successfully merged all columns from df2 to df1.
but now I just need to add two columns on the basis of common column "id"

I am using `python 3.7` version.

```
df_right = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',on='id')
```

how can I merge only these two columns ('sal' and 'deg') from df2 on the basis of 'id'?

Answer (score 3):

Just go slice before you merge like so.

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2[['id', 'sal', 'deg']], how='right', on='id')
```

Comment: I have already tried this one. it gives me KeyError: 'id' can you please tell me why this error is coming.

Comment: well are you sure 'id' is a column or an index? cause "KeyError" means that it's not a column in one of the dataframes.

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure. as I removed [ ] with columns name mentioned within it. it is working fine fetching all the columns from df2. can you please suggest something.

Comment: solved now it is working fine. I was just missing 'id' into [ ].